# Does gel deodorant count as "liquids"?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage

My new deodorant doesn't come in travel size but a 3.4oz. It's a clear gel in the common deodorant container with holes at the top.  Now is taking this through security at any airport going to be problem? If so, how do you all take your deodorants? Never really thought about this situation before.

Comment: In fact, the prohibition/limits are about “liquids, aeorosols and gels” (cf. e.g. [EU rules](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/aviation-security-policy/lags_en.htm)). Also, I don't use deodorant at all.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, of course it counts as "liquids". But 3.4oz (per product) is [actually the limit](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/3-1-1-liquids-rule) of what you can take in carry-on baggage. So put it in a zip-top bag, place that one separately when you're at the security screening, and you're fine.

Personally, I don't want to bother with all that and instead take a small stick-type solid deodorant in my carry-on.

Comment: Mine is in a stick type container but I need to need to use a specific brand which is gel. Their solid white one sucks.   I thought 3oz was the limit. So 3.4 oz is okay?

Comment: @verve: it's often called the "3-1-1 rule" for simplicity's sake, but the actual limit is 100 mililiters (even from the USA's TSA, I'll add a link), which is 3.4 ounces.

Comment: I really miss things too often.  Lol.  Need a new brain.